# Adding Pop ups to google Maps Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have been following a tutorial to add google maps markers to a google maps map and use clusters when they are close to each other.

I have the clustering working, but I also want to add more than just the title to the pop-up. I would like to add a description with custom HTML that is different to each one.

HTML:

```
<select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
  <option value="">All Markers</option>
  <option value="backpacking">Backpacking</option>
  <option value="hiking">Hiking</option>
  <option value="offRoad">Off Road</option>
</select>

<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: ''
});
var markerCluster;

// Our markers
markers1 = [
  ['0', 'Tanner Trail Grand Canyon', 36.0326, -111.8525, 'backpacking'],
  ['1', 'Yosemite Snow Shoe Badger Pass', 37.6648, -119.6634, 'backpacking'],
  ['2', 'Kayak Camping Catalina Island', 33.3504, -118.3282, 'backpacking'],
  ['3', 'Mini Trans Catalina Trail', 33.3403, -118.3262, 'backpacking']
];

/**
 * Function to init map
 */

function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(52.4357808, 4.991315699999973);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    addMarker(markers1[i]);
  }
  markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers1, {
    imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclustererplus/images/m'
  });
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */

function addMarker(marker) {
  var category = marker[4];
  var title = marker[1];
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
  var content = marker[1];

  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: title,
    position: pos,
    category: category,
    map: map
  });

  gmarkers1.push(marker1);

  // Marker click listener
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker1, content) {
    return function() {
      console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
      infowindow.setContent(content);
      infowindow.open(map, marker1);
      map.panTo(this.getPosition());
      //map.setZoom(15);
    }
  })(marker1, content));
}

/**
 * Function to filter markers by category
 */

filterMarkers = function(category) {
  var newmarkers = [];
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers1[i];
    // If is same category or category not picked
    if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
      marker.setVisible(true);
      newmarkers.push(marker);
    }
    // Categories don't match 
    else {
      marker.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
  markerCluster.clearMarkers();
  markerCluster.addMarkers(newmarkers);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

Please check out this JSfiddle for what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/seekAdventure/bqcp1vns/24/

Comment: The code here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

Only shows with one marker and doesn't show how to attach it to a specific marker which is where my confusion is to have different info for each marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "InfoWindows" for this. See:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

*[Edit]* for better reading of my comment:

```js
// Our markers
markers1 = [
  ['0', 'Tanner Trail Grand Canyon', 36.0326, -111.8525, 'backpacking', '<h1>Some fancy HTML stuff</h1><p>...goes in here</p>'],
];

// [...]

function addMarker(marker) {
  var category = marker[4];
  var title = marker[1];
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
  // get html string from marker array:
  var content = marker[5]; 

  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: title,
    position: pos,
    category: category,
    map: map
  });

  gmarkers1.push(marker1);

  // Marker click listener
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker1, content) {
    return function() {
      console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
      infowindow.setContent(content);
      infowindow.open(map, marker1);
      map.panTo(this.getPosition());
      //map.setZoom(15);
    }
  })(marker1, content));
}
```

Comment: I found them, but I am having trouble fitting them into my array so each marker has his own pop up description

Comment: Acually you already did it. Take a look at Line 45 of your Javascript/JS Fiddle:
```var content = marker[1];```
That's the content of the marker. It currently uses the title of the marker, (item [1] of your marker array, but you can extend your marker array.
e.g.
```['0', 'Tanner Trail Grand Canyon', 36.0326, -111.8525, 'backpacking', '<h1>Some fancy html</h2>]```
and change it to ```var content = marker[5];```